# Windows 10 UEFI usb power off issue

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, uefi

Wanted result Windows 10 installed in EFI boot mode in bios.

First i setup boot mode in bios to be EFI And here start my problem, so i have 2 windows(x64 isos) on another pc one is under the 4gb and the other is above 4 gb.

Problem :

Note : i tried so many programs(without success) to make bootable usb but lets say that we`ll stick to the rufus because everywhere in internet uses this program to achieve my goal in usb3 port.

So if i try to make EFI usb within windows above 4GB, the usb file system must be something else then fat32(it is not possible fat32 to handle files bigger than 4 gb and rufus dont allow me to start).

With rufus version above 1.8 it is possible to make "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" with file system NTFS so i made it, but after i tried on the laptop, it appear this menu with available device on the pc and when try to use the usb drive nothing happens it returns me on the same menu to select the device that i want.

So i tried to do the usb how it is ment to be "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" with fat32 file system with my windows that is under 4gb, and after that i tried on the laptop, and here the different is that this menu with available devices doesn`t appear and directly i receive [this screen](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9YinveHjdq_OFVyT1NUUVV2TEU) which is a think is the background of the windows, and after that my pc is shutted down. So any suggestion what to do :?

Note: if i change boot mode to be on legacy mode im able to boot via usb, but then when im trying to install Ubuntu i have another issue, because Windows is installed on legacy mode and ubuntu tries to install on EFI mode but i think if i`m able to install windows under the efi mode this error will desappear

Comment: If you are using NTFS with GPT in Rufus, you __MUST__ disable Secure Boot in your UEFI firmware options. You can re-enable it afterwards, but the UEFI bootloader that enable NTFS boot is not signed for Secure Boot (and cannot be, because it's GPLv3 and Microsoft forbids the signing of GPLv3 binaries) so Secure Boot needs to be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my ASUS laptop. 
Turns out that when you run it in UEFI mode you can't choose boot device on first run right after you power it on.
Instead you have to restart the machine once it boots up and on 2nd run you can choose the boot device from menu.
You can restart it on bootloader screen with ctrl+alt+del if you have any custom bootloader installed or just wait until it finishes booting and then restart it - just don't hard-reset it.